# How to bring a function result into another function

Tags: node.js

I have two functions. First one is taking a piece of text (*orgText*) and translate it to english. The result is within *res.text*.

I need to bring *res.text* to the toneAnalyzer. Right now i've put the original text in, just to be sure that the API call is working. It does.

So the basic question is: "How do I swap *orgText* with *res.text* in the toneAnalyzer?

```
app.post('/api/tone', function(req, res, next) {

  var orgText= req.body;


  //Translating input from danish to english
var translate = require('yandex-translate')('key');

translate.translate(orgText.text, { to: 'en' }, function (err, res) {
console.log(res.text);
});
// Translate end

toneAnalyzer.tone(orgText, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  return res.json(data);
});


});
```

I have tried to move the toneAnalyzer function into the translation function, but i get this error:

```
error: { code: 500, error: 'Missing required parameters: text' }
```

The output from the console.log on orgText looks like this:

```
{ text:
   'Jeg var meget glad for den lige i starten, men så begyndte den desværre at gå i stykker.\nJeg er meget tilfreds, og vil elske hvis jeg kunne få råd til en mere.\nDet er det værste ragelse jeg nogensinde har ejet. Den virkede kun i sølle 2 dage.\n\n',
  language: 'en' }
```

....and the out put from res.text looks like this:

```
[ 'I was very glad the right in the beginning, but then started, unfortunately, to go in pieces.\nI am very satisfied, and would love if I could get advice for a more.\nIt is the worst junk I have ever owned. It was only in a measly 2 days.\n\n' ]
```

There's some formatting going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm saying in [my post about callbacks](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html), move the code that needs the value to where the value is. That means moving the `toneAnalyzer.tone` call inside the `translate` callback:

```
app.post('/api/tone', function(req, res, next) {

  var orgText = req.body;

  //Translating input from danish to english
  var translate = require('yandex-translate')('trnsl.1.1.20190501T085025Z.d0e7ff2611e9f05a.d4ef69a7a21f28712b67991325adbf74abf72c8b');

  translate.translate(orgText.text, {to: 'en'}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
      return;
    }
    toneAnalyzer.tone(res.text, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.json(data);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Yeah. That was also my first idea, but i get an error from the toneAnalyzer API:
_Missing required parameters: text_

Comment: The console.log output from orgText looks like this:
_{ text:
   'Jeg var meget glad for den lige i starten, men så begyndte den desværre at gå i stykker.\nJeg er meget tilfreds, og vil elske hvis jeg kunne få råd til en mere.\nDet er det værste ragelse jeg nogensinde har ejet. Den virkede kun i sølle 2 dage.\n\n',
  language: 'en' }_

Comment: And the output from res.text looks like this:
_ [ 'I was very glad the right in the beginning, but then started, unfortunately, to go in pieces.\nI am very satisfied, and would love if I could get advice for a more.\nIt is the worst junk I have ever owned. It was only in a measly 2 days.\n\n' ]_

Comment: So `res.text` is an array? Maybe you have to access the first element of the array instead. Read up on the API documentation of the `translate` function to lean what it returns.

Comment: I don't think it could be the `translate` function since the text is actually being translated. But it is stripping the json format somehow

Comment: Uh? The `translate` function passes the value of `res` to the callback, so yeah, it's absolutely related to that. Read up on its documentation to figure out what that value is, and how to pass the right value to `tone`. At this point it's all about what values these APIs generate. The general structure of the code is correct. *"since the text is actually being translated"*  Sure, but if `tone` expects a string  and `res.text` is not a string, then it's wrong. What does `console.log(Array.is(res.text))` say?

Comment: console.log(Array.is(res.text)) says: _TypeError: Array.is is not a function_

I will read up on the API. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DennisHolmgreen: Whoops, that should be `Array.isArray(...)` of course.

Comment: Ahhh ok. It says: 
`true
error: { code: 500, error: 'Missing required parameters: text' }`

Comment: Yes. I get same result. I've also tried to convert it to a string but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Oh. I guess the function expects an object with property `text`. Then try passing `res` itself or `{text: res.text[0]}`. If it also needs a `language` property then you have to provide one as well.

Comment: Ok. This gets even more strange. With `{text: res.text[0], language: 'en'}` i get the exact same result as the `orgText` output. But still it throws the error that it's missing the parameter 'text'. 

When i use `orgText` with the toneAnalyzer function inside the translate function, I get this error: `TypeError: res.json is not a function`

Comment: Then you have to read more about the toneAnalyzer API and what values it expects. Can’t help you here.

Comment: I managed to fix it: When I moved the `toneAnalyzer` inside the `translate` as requested, the declaration `res` in app.post (first line) was unsused because it was reset in the `translate` function. I simply renamed app.post declaration to `response` and did the same for `response.json(data)`.